# What is the fastest drive with a ZIF interface?

Tags: hard-drive, netbook, sata

I'm shopping around for a new drive to replace the SSD in my Aspire One netbook. Looking at reviews and quick write ups it would appear that the fastest drives are only reading at ~ 80 to 85MB/s and writing at half that.

Is there a faster alternative that will fit in my Aspire One (zg5, AOA110-1955 with the Intel 8gig SSD) without too much modification (i.e. soldering)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with cheap (MLC) netbook SSDs is indeed the write speed. **[FlashFire](http://flashfire.org/xe/)** is a software solution that should solve the issue, basically it's using system memory as write cache:

- FlashFire is software for Solid-State Drives
- FlashFire uses host RAM to enhance random write performance of a SSD
- FlashFire is especially useful for the system using low-end SSDs

I know it helps a great deal with certain Eee PC models that shipped with poor performing MLC SSDs (e.g. the Eee PC 900/16), even speeds up the SLC SSD performance in my Eee PC 701. Try it first before spending money on upgrading a rather cheap netbook.

Here is a ATTO Disk Benchmark comparison, without FlashFire:

[image]

with FlashFire:

[image]

Of course, there are many more tweaks to improve the performance of such SSDs, over at eeeuser.com is a quite informative [thread](http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=37047) dealing with the matter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give that a shot. I'm running ubuntu netbook remix on it at the moment - is there a linux version of FlashFire (or similar)? I do want to install a vLite'ed version of Win 7 but I was waiting until I got a new hdd.

Comment: @Rob Allen - no Linux version, sorry. and with that SSD i'd refrain from installing Windows 7, even with every NTFS tweak under the sun, it will be painfully slow, grab XP and nLite the heck out of it. best you can do with an Atom processor and MLC SSD.

Comment: @molly - that's why I'm looking for a new drive first. I've seen 7 running nicely (vLited) on some netbooks with 4200 RPM PATA drives and some MLC SSDs (just not the cheapy intel)

Comment: @Rob Allen - well, nicely is a stretchable term :) yes, i had 7 running on my 701 4G with 2 GB RAM and it was 'all right' at best, and this one got quite a speedy SLC-type SSD (boot time around 45 sec which still beats the heck out of some hi-powered laptop with platter HDD but nothing compared to XP which boots in less than 20 sec), i'd say there is no gain in 7 and 7 can't really do anything for you that XP couldn't do as well. Your Acer One can't do Aero Glass and DirectX11 anyway. :)